# How to use typescript on redux connected components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

How do I type props that are connected to a reducer?

Following code gives typescript errors but works in runtime.

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="test">
        <p>{this.props.value}</p> // Typescript error
        <button onClick={() => this.props.setValue(3)}> click</button> // Typescript error
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => ({
  value: state.calcReducer.value as number,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  setValue,
})(Sidebar);
```

Comment: You have typescript errors, but the code still compiles?

Comment: Yes the generated js-files is valid.

Comment: Dont know if this will solve your issue, but when working with typescript and redux, I found this article super helpful. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/04/20/typesafe-container-components/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `type` on your props like this:

```
interface IProps {
  value: number;
  setValue: (value: number) => void;
}

class Sidebar extends React.Component<IProps> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  // Your code ...
}
```

---

If you want to get rid of the `any` keywords as well you can give this a try.

```
interface IYourState {/* Your code */}

interface IYourOwnProps {/* Your code */}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IYourState, ownProps: IYourOwnProps) => ({
  value: state.calcReducer.value as number,
});

export default connect<IYourState, {}, IYourOwnProps>(mapStateToProps, {
  setValue,
})(Sidebar);
```

Here is the type definition of the `connect()` function of `react-redux` in case you want to investigate further. Note that I have marked the line `109` so you should start around there first.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L109

Comment: Never mind, I think I probably get it. I have updated the answer. Please give it one more try.

Answer (score -2):

You need to define the Props type and the State type the component is expected to have so as to ignore typescript error.

You can implement something like this.

```
interface Props {
    value: number;               // Props type of the component.
    setValue: (number: int) => void;
}

interface State {
                               //  State type of the component  
}

class Sidebar extends React.Component<Props, State> {  // edited -need to pass interfaces
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="test">
        <p>{this.props.value}</p> // Typescript error
        <button onClick={() => this.props.setValue(3)}> click</button> // Typescript error
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => ({
  value: state.calcReducer.value as number,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  setValue: (number: int) => dispatch(setValue(number)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sidebar);
```

I hope it may help you to solve the typescript error.Thanks!!

**edited.

Comment: Well, my question was how to connect the interface to the reducer in redux.

Comment: Define setValue function also in the Prop types then you will not receive any typescript error. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Ahh Sorry, I don't know how I missed it. You need to pass interfaces Props and state to the Component too. I just updated my answer. Please check.